# Fractional Transaction Count

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21930156/transaction-count-after-execute-indicates-a-mismatching-number-of-begin-and-comm) I understand the meaning of the following sorts of errors:

> Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 0.

However I'm seeing:

> Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, **current count = 0.266**

I find a fractional transaction count to be equal parts funny, scary, and odd. I'm sorry I don't have a simple script to share that would reproduce.

Can anyone explain this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I feel silly. I eventually saw this again, but it said "current count = 2.266" I thought that was again strange.

And then I noticed that 266 was the error number. Hmm.

***Facepalm***

Turns out I inherited some boiler plate error handling that was appending the error number to the error message without any separation. So what looked for all the world like a wacky ms thing, was in fact a wacky construct. I must have looked at it 100 times without seeing the actual problem.